# Calculate grand total in oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

How to calculate grand total in query in SQL developer in oracle.

Break on report
Compute Sum is not working in SQL developer.It works only in SQL plus.
Don't want to use group function also.
Is there any way to run a query in SQL developer and show the total at the end of the results/rows.
Also want to use it in jdbc java the query

For Example , i need to select a table and list all records matching certain criteria and show the sum at the end of the records

```
Select volume, value , *.t1 from table1 t1 where trunc(create_date) = trunc(sysdate)
```

This will display say 50 records..i want to display at the end of all records under column volume and value ,the grand total of these 2 columns.

```
        Volume  value   xxx  yy  zzzz
        25       123.5  aa   bb   cc
        35       10     a    c    b
        50       100    c   nn    xc
    
       --        --
       110       233.5
```

Comment: Run the query with F5, it will run as in SQL*Plus

Comment: i want to use without F5 as i need it run in jdbc java similarly

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot calculate totals without calculation of totals. Either `group by` or calculate it on the app side.

Comment: or via window functions.  We can also use recursion to iterate over a list to provide a SUM-like behavior.  So there are a few ways to aggregate.  Not all include `GROUP BY`.  It's tough to guess what the OP really needs.

Comment: @user1929905 Try to provide a full / clear requirement, with data and expected result. `I don't want to` doesn't really help unless you can explain why you `don't want to` or `can't`.

Comment: edited the question with more explanation

Comment: Your update still have no reason why you try to avoid `group by`. Please, clarify what is allowed to use from your point of view or why you are so strict regarding group by.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query to achieve the result -

```
SELECT volume,
       value ,
       t1.*
  FROM table1 t1
 WHERE TRUNC(create_date) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
 UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(volume),
       SUUM(value),
       NULL,
       NULL,  
       ...  -- Add other NULLS according to your column list in table1.
  FROM table1;
```

Comment: is there any way without using group by

Comment: When you need the grand total, That means you are already getting a total by SUM function. If you are already using SUM function, You have to use GROUP BY. It would be Better if you can post your query and expected result here also?

Comment: added more detail

Answer (score 0):

"I don't want" is a poor reason.

How come you can & want to use SQL*Plus' commands (which won't work elsewhere), but standard SQL capabilities are out of your sight? I'd suggest you to reconsider what you said & thought.

If you do, **rollup** might be a nice option for you.

```
SQL> select deptno,
  2         sum(sal) sum_sal,
  3         sum(comm) sum_comm
  4  from emp
  5  group by rollup(deptno);

    DEPTNO    SUM_SAL   SUM_COMM
---------- ---------- ----------
        10       8750
        20      10875
        30       9400       2200
                29025       2200

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROLLUP` FUNCTION here.

```
SELECT SUM (volume) volume,
           SUM (value) value,
           xxx
FROM table1 t1
WHERE TRUNC (create_date) = TRUNC (SYSDATE)
GROUP BY ROLLUP (xxx)
```